# How to Search for a [FieldName] in Spring Data JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm a newbie to Spring framework. I'm stuck at the basic CRUD functionalities. What I was trying to do is search for a username and then determine whether if the password entered is correct. For now I'm trying to at least just find for specific username in my Entities. How do I do that in Spring JPA?. I could only search through using ID's, but not FieldNames. I wanted to implement it like this in Service.
List findCredentialsByUsername(String username);

And call this Service in my controller to which I would search for a username using Postman/browser url.

The method in the Controller would then have something like this 
credentialsRepository.findCredentialsByUsername(username); 
That is not using Queries, just the basic JPA methods.

And whenever that is found,it would return true or at least give me details with that username.

I have the following Entity.

```
@Entity
public class Credentials {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;

@Column
String username;
@Column
String password;
@Column
String firstname;
@Column
String lastname;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

//ToString , Getters and Setters
//Needed for returning the changes on POSTMAN
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Credentials{" +
            "username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
            ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
```

}

My Controllers, Services and Repository is quite a mess.I can't quite get the hang of building blocks of this thing Spring data JPA?. I've been crawling the web for days for this basic building blocks for JPA using CRUD. :/

PS:

> The password is unencrypted on DB. For a basic Spring JPA, I just wanted to do a basic Search / CRUD if possible.
>   No Web UI is created, I'm just doing the testing of my CRUD functionalities via Postman

Comment: "Can anyone help" is not a good question here. What have you tried, what did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead. Be very precise. Post the relevant code and the error, if any. Note: there is no such thing as "Spring JPA". There is JPA, and there is spring-data-jpa. If your question is about the latter, have you read its documentation? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: I did read it, unfortunately, I can't find a way to pass it through the Controller for testing in postman as I'm new to Postma. I could add D record through it alright, but the way of how values is being passed from the Service, to Controller and then Postman is what I dont understand just yet. Hence I was trying to get the basics of the paramter passing, and one way I know should be easy to do is through this simple query w/o using JPQL. All the other examples having the search in the documentation however already has the predefined search, what I needed was dynamic through postman input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for **query methods** just use the keyword **findBy** fallowed by the **field name**

Example : **findBy**Username(String username)

[Query methods section for more information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)

So you just have to create an **interface** that extends **JpaRepository** or **CrudRepository** :

```
@Repository
public interface CredentialsRepository extends JpaRepository<Credentials, Long> {

  Optional<Credentials> findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Then your controller :

```
@RestController
public class CredentialsController {

  @Autowired
  CredentialsRepository credentialsRepository;

  @GetMapping("/check/{username}")
  public String check(@PathVariable("username") String username) {

   Optional<Credentials> credentials = CredentialsRepository.findByUsername(username);

   return credentials.isPresent() ? "exist" : "doesn't exist"; 

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. Turns out I was using  search/findByUsername?username=[search value] with that GetMapping value instead of just search/[search value]. Even then I was passing the values from Postman to Controller the wrong way, thanks.

Comment: welcome @iamjoshua , if you want to use **findByUsername?username=[search value]** you just have to use **@RequestParam** instead of **@PathVariable**